# What does .sprite file refers to?

Tags: liferay, sprite, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I'm using Liferay Portal 6, The .sprite file is not specified in the source code, however, it's included in the URL with a slash dot, then it's blocked by a security program.
When I delete those file in theme/docroot/images and I deploy the project, they are generated again.
I would like to know how to manage those files or rename them?

Answer (score 0):

You can open those files: It's combined images - look up "CSS Sprite" for a thorough documentation. They're used to limit the number of requests that go back to the server. Without sprites, you'd have every theme image loaded individually. With them you only need the sprite once, resulting in a significant performance boost: You want to have as few http-requests per page as possible, and sprites are one automatically handled way to help you achieving this.

Comment: Thank you @Olaf for your response, Is there any .properties file used to manage the .sprite file in order to rename them?